# No quiere validar condicional

Tags: php

Estoy realizando una ventana de ayuda, en el que al momento de validar si el usuario existe empiezo a recoger todas las variables

```
if($count){
$data = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$_SESSION['pantalla_ayuda'] = $data->pantalla_ayuda;
```

Si el campo `pantalla_ayuda` es igual a 1 me manda a una pagina

Si el campo `pantalla_ayuda` es igual a 0 me manda al inicio

Esta condiicional lo estoy haciendo directamente desde el `if($count)`

Quedando asi:

```
//Si los datos son correctos -->
if($count){
$data = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$_SESSION['pantalla_ayuda'] = $data->pantalla_ayuda;
if ($_SESSION['pantalla_ayuda'] = 1){
   header('location: ../instrucciones.php');
}else if($_SESSION['pantalla_ayuda'] = 0){
   header('location: ../inicio.php');
}
//Si los datos son incorrectos -->
    }else{
        echo '<script>
alert("Usuario o Clave incorrectas");
window.history.go(-1);
</script>';
    }
```

La cosa es que sin importar que tenga el campo siempre me manda a instrucciones.php, que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Intenta con `if ($_SESSION['pantalla_ayuda'] == 1){`

Comment: En lugar de comparar, estás asignando un valor `if ($_SESSION['pantalla_ayuda'] = 1)` y la evaluación sería: _Si se puede asignar el valor_, siempre será verdadero. debes usar doble signo igual: `if ($_SESSION['pantalla_ayuda'] == 1)`

Comment: al intentar usar == y aunque el usuario tenga el campo en 1 me manda al inicio

Comment: @ernestojimenez necesitamos detalles de la consulta y lo que vale `$count` si le haces un var_dump, pero de que tienes un error con = eso es un hecho, pues para comparar se usan 2 (idealmente 3)

Comment: la validacion de datos me lo toma bien, lo que me esta fallando es en ese campo al querer validar si es 1 o es 0

Comment: Antes del `if` agrega `var_dump($_SESSION['pantalla_ayuda']); die();` y cuéntanos lo que aparece.

Comment: Disculpen un error de mi parte, resulto ser que ademas de lo que mencionaron se me olvido obtener del select ese campo, cuando intentaba hacer un echo la variable no existe, por eso no lo validaba

Answer (score 0):

Intenta obtener el valor de
`$data` en la ejecución simplemente estás checando si es falso, true ó null, si hubiera sido null te accionaba el último else.
// Puedes agregar una alerta antes del header()

```
//if ($_SESSION['pantalla_ayuda'] = 1){
if ($_SESSION['pantalla_ayuda'] == 1){
echo '<script> alert(" Debug: " ' .  $data . ');</script>'; 
//header('location: ../instrucciones.php');

//}else if($_SESSION['pantalla_ayuda'] = 0){
}else if($_SESSION['pantalla_ayuda'] === 0){

echo '<script> alert(" Debug: " ' .  $data . ');</script>'; 
header('location: ../inicio.php');
}
```

//continuar..

Comment: Hola amigo, en los comentarios ya indique que el error era porque no me estaba trayendo la data que necesitaba para validar, pero de igual forma gracias por tu respuesta